# Java decrypt email attachment (.p7m file)

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, cryptography, smime

I have an email attachment in .p7m format and a .pem file containing private keys and certificates.
Using OpenSSL I can decrypt the file with this command:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -inform DER -in fileToDecrypt.p7m -inkey privateKey.pem -out destinationFile
```

But using bouncycastle in Java, I could not decrypt it.
I read the private key with this code:

```
    PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(privateKeyName)));
    Object obj;
    PrivateKey key = null;
    X509Certificate cert1 = null;
    X509Certificate cert2 = null;

    obj = pemReader.readObject();
    if (obj instanceof PrivateKey) {
        key = (PrivateKey) obj;
        System.out.println("Private Key found");
    }
    obj = pemReader.readObject();
    if(obj instanceof X509Certificate){
        cert1 = (X509Certificate) obj;
        System.out.println("cert found");
    }
    obj = pemReader.readObject();
    if(obj instanceof X509Certificate){
        cert2 = (X509Certificate) obj;
        System.out.println("cert found");
    }
```

This prints out:

```
Private Key Found
cert found
cert found
```

The type of the keys are:

```
 System.out.println(key.getAlgorithm());
 System.out.println(cert1.getSigAlgName());
 System.out.println(cert2.getSigAlgName());

RSA
SHA256WithRSAEncryption
SHA256WithRSAEncryption
```

If I try to decrypt like this:

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
 Path path = Paths.get("fileToDecrypt.p7m");
 byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
 byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

I get:

`javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes`

I have this two files:

1. fileToDecrypt.p7m
2. privateKey.pem: containing RSA private key and two X508 Certificates

And I don't know where to begin what to decrypt with what, and how?

Comment: you can answer you own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem:

```
private static byte[] cmsDecrypt(byte[] message, PrivateKey key) throws
        Exception {
    CMSEnvelopedDataParser ep = new CMSEnvelopedDataParser(message);
    RecipientInformationStore recipients = ep.getRecipientInfos();
    Collection c = recipients.getRecipients();
    Iterator iter = c.iterator();
    RecipientInformation recipient = (RecipientInformation) iter.next();
    return recipient.getContent(key, new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

---

```
Path path = Paths.get("fileToDecrypt.p7m");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
try {
    System.out.println(new String(cmsDecrypt(data, key)));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Incomplete answer, without any explanation of what the problem or solution was